# PONS online - Warum ändert sich die IPA Lautschrift zwischen Sprachen?

Tags: dictionary, phonetics

Ich hätte eine Frage für all jene die mit der online Version des PONS Wörterbuches vertraut sind:

**Warum ändert sich die IPA Transkription je nach dem welche Übersetzungssprache ich auswähle?**

Im Rahmen einer Studie bräuchte ich die offizielle deutsche Lautschrift für gewisse Wörter, verstehe aber nicht warum zum Beispiel das Wort BESEN im DE-EN Wörterbuch als [ˈbe:zn̩] und im DE-FR Wörterbuch als [ˈbeːzən] transkribiert wird.

Sollte die Lautschrift nicht unverändert bleiben? Welcher Bezug hat die Übersetzungssprache auf die Weise in der das Wort in Hochdeutsch ausgesprochen wird?

Comment: Eine "ofizielle" deutsche Lautschrift gibt es nicht. Die Aussprache von (selbst) Hochdeutsch variiert massiv zwischen Regionen, Sozialisierungen, Situationen,..., so dass das, was du im Lexikon findest, nur eine Annäherung sein kann.

Comment: Na gut;

Welchen Standard folgt der Pons Verlag ? 

Bereits dem des Deutschen Sprachraumes und nicht des Österreichischen nehme ich an aber über welche Region ? Hat die phonetische Approximation einen geographischen Ursprung ? 

Und warum sollte diese Annäherung sich je nach Fremdsprache ändern ? Sollte der Pons Verlag nicht in allen Fällen seine eigenen Richtlinien befolgen ?

Comment: Weil es regionale und andere Unterschiede in der Artikulation bei manchen Wörtern gibt, sodass mehrere Lautschriften richtig sein können. Warum das Pons-Wörterbuch diese Dinge nicht nur einmal speichert, fragst du sinnvollerweise deren Betreiber, nicht Stack Exchange.

Comment: Wohl wahr, wohl wahr. Es wäre zu einfach gewesen hätte es dafür einen offensichtlichen Grund gegeben der mir nicht klar war. Danke euch beiden für eure Antworten.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt keinen allgemeinen Standard für IPA-Umschriften. Wörterbücher definieren üblicherweise ihren eigenen Hausstandard, der dann im Rahmen des jeweiligen Wörterbuchs gilt.

Ein Grund dafür, warum in einem deutsch-englischen Wörterbuch das Wort *Besen* als [ˈbe:zn̩] umgeschrieben ist, in einem deutsch-französischen Wörterbuch hingegen als [ˈbeːzən], könnte in einem Unterschied zwischen den typischen phonetischen Umschriften für Englisch und Französisch liegen.

In phonetischen Umschriften der englischen Sprache ist die Verwendung von silbischen Konsonanten relativ verbreitet, beispielsweiser bei einer Umschrift des Worts *sudden* als [ˈsʌdn̩]. Der Grund dafür könnte wiederum in der englischen Orthographie liegen, wo die entsprechenden Laute teilweise ohne Vokalbuchstaben geschrieben werden, beispielsweise in Wörtern wie *prism* [ˈprɪzm̩]. Ein englisch-deutsches Wörterbuch könnte also die silbischen Konsonanten, die bereits für das Englische eingeführt worden sind, ebenfalls für das Deutsche verwenden und ein Wort wie *Besen* in phonetischer Umschrift als [ˈbe:zn̩] widergeben.

Im Französischen hingegen sind phonetische Umschriften mit silbischen Konsonanten weniger üblich. Ein französisch-deutsches Wörterbuch könnte also ganz auf die Einführung von silbischen Konsonanten verzichten und ein deutsches Wort wie *Besen* in phonetischer Umschrift als [ˈbeːzən] widergeben.

Der Unterschied zwischen den Umschriften [ˈbe:zn̩] und [ˈbeːzən] für das Wort *Besen* liegt übrigens nicht so sehr in regionalen Ausspracheunterschieden, sondern eher in einem Entscheid für eine etwas engere Transkription, die mehr Aussprachenuancen widergibt, aber dafür auch mehr Sonderzeichen verwendet, und einer etwas breiteren Transkription, die weniger Aussprachenuancen unterscheidet, dafür aber auch auf Sonderzeichen verzichten kann.

Answer (score -1):

Ich würde sagen (für Deutschland), dass man z. B. die Aussprache, in der Nachrichten im Radio oder Tagesschau vorgetragen werden, als "Hochdeutsch" und "Standard" betrachten kann. Trotzdem wird diese Aussprache sich von Region zu Region und Sprecher zu Sprecher unterscheiden. Insbesondere in dem von Dir genannten Fall des [ə], das irgendwo zwischen deutlich als unbetontes e artikuliert und völlig verschwunden auftreten kann. Auch die Unterscheidung von ä und e oder i und ü ist nicht immer sehr deutlich. Genauso wird das r z. B. in Franken oder Bayern anders ausgesprochen als im Norden. Dort beginnt dann schon "dialektale Färbung", es ist aber immer noch korrektes Hochdeutsch.

Ich nehme an, dass sich alle Unterschiede, die Du in der Aussprache zwischen zwei Pons-Ausgaben finden kannst, in diesem schmalen Bereich befinden.

Interessant würde es, wenn Du Unterschiede wie [ç]/[ʃ]/[χ] in "Kirche" (Hochdeutsch/rheinischer Akzent bzw. Dialekt/bairischer Sprachraum) findest, das glaube ich aber nicht.

Comment: Summa summarum : da Sprache in seiner Natur selbst eine multidimensionale Dynamik inne hat, gibt es keinen einzelnen goldenen Standard, keine einzelne "richtige" Hochdeutsche Aussprache. Wir bewegen uns immer in einem, wie du sagst, "schmalen Bereich", von leichten Variationen der breitbandig als Hochdeutsch akzeptiert wird. Wie entscheidet ein Wörterbuch Verlag nach welchen Richtlinien er sich richtet ? Gibt es eine systematische Herangehensweise (e.g. die mehrheitliche Tendenz aller Variationen) oder ist das völlig arbiträr dem Verlag überlassen ? (e.g. wir sind in Bayern, basta)

Comment: Wie wonderbear schon sagt, ich glaube da musst Du den Wörterbuchverlag fragen.

Comment: Downvote: warum sollte ausgerechnet die Tagesschau oder sonst eine (Radio-)Sendung definieren, was "Standard" ist? Beleg?

Comment: Die definieren das nicht, aber Radionachrichten und Tagesschau sind meines Erachtens die Quellen einer Aussprache, die es dem größten Teil der deutschen Bevölkerung erlaubt, dem Gesprochenen problemlos zu folgen (zumindest was die Aussprache angeht; Grammatik und Vokabular schließe ich jetzt mal aus). Was jetzt Henne und was Ei ist, weiß ich nicht, aber Sprache ist ja stetig im Fluss, und ich denke dass sich Aussprachegepflogenheiten in der breiten Bevölkerung auch im Radio und Fernsehen widerspiegeln.

Comment: Natürlich könnte man jetzt noch argumentieren, dass die Tagesschau ja vorrangig ein NDR-Produkt ist und damit die norddeutsche Aussprache tendenziell dominant ist, aber auch hier weiß ich nicht was zuerst da war. Ich kann nur aus persönlicher Erfahrung bestätigen, dass ich als Südniedersachse im gesamten bundesdeutschen Sprachraum und meistens auch in der Schweiz und Österreich problemlos verstanden werde, was umgekehrt nicht immer der Fall ist.