# Passivumschreibungen

Tags: passive

Bezüglich des Satzes "Diese Theorie kann bewiesen werden" bin ich mir folgender Umschreibungen bewusst:

> 1. Diese Theorie lässt sich beweisen. (Das Wort "sich" scheint hier im Akkusativ zu stehen.)
> 2. Diese Theorie ist zu beweisen.

Bei transitiven Verben funktionieren die oben genannten Umschreibungsweisen ohne Schwierigkeit. Aber wie wäre es mit intransitiven Verben?

> 3. Er lässt sich helfen. (Das Wort "sich" scheint hier im Dativ zu stehen.)
> 4. Ihm ist zu helfen.

Die Umschreibungsweise mit "lassen" bereitet mir Schwierigkeiten, insbesondere wenn das Verb kein Nomen regiert.

> 5. Dagegen lässt sich argumentieren.
> 6. Dagegen ist zu argumentieren.

Sätze wie (5) sind in Korpora zu finden. Aber was für eine syntaktische Rolle spielt "sich" darin?

Edit: Statt (3) und (4) würde ich neue Beispielsätze mit sachlichem Subjekt vorschlagen, damit man sie nicht als Ausdrücke von Erlaubnis oder Notwendigkeit lesen würde.

> (III) Diese Theorie lässt sich nicht wiedersprechen.

> (IV) Dieser Theorie ist nicht zu wiedersprechen.

Comment: Das erste Wort in einem deutschen Satz beginnt immer mit einem Großbuchstaben, und am Ende eines Aussagesatzes muss immer ein Punkt stehen. Ich habe das in allen Beispielsätzen korrigiert und habe bei dieser Gelegenheit auch andere Fehler ausgebessert.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch, questions and answers in German are welcome on German SE.

Comment: Looking at the questions and answers here, I see none completly in German @CarstenS

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch, you will find some if you look closer, but it is indeed a problem that we don't make this clearer to newcomers. https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/640/3237

Comment: We also have a meta question somewhere which has the outcome that we prefer answers to be in the same language as the question.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch: Meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487 High rated and old questions in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/928/1487 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/329/1487 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3230/1487 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1433/1487 New questions in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/73954/1487 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/73943/1487 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/73935/1487

Answer (score 2):

Der **Satz 1** (*»Diese Theorie lässt sich beweisen«*) ist nach dem Muster des reflexiven Passiv gebaut, der manchmal auch  *"sich"-Passiv* genannt wird. Der reflexive Passiv ist ein Subtyp eines Vorgangspassiv. Hier sind einige Beispiele dafür:

> Das Buch liest sich gut.
> Das Auto fährt sich ziemlich gut.
> Die Arbeit macht sich nicht von selbst.

Sehr häufig wird der reflexive Passiv aber mit dem Verb *»lassen«* kombiniert:

> Die Butter lässt sich gut streichen.
> Lisas Katze lässt sich gerne streicheln.
> Heute lasse ich mich herumkutschieren.

Der reflexive Passiv wird verwendet, um einen möglichen Vorgang zum Ausdruck zu bringen. Man könnte ihn daher auch als *Möglichkeits-Passiv* bezeichnen. Mit dem reflexiven Passiv wird also nur ausgesagt, dass es die Möglichkeit gibt, einen bestimmten Vorgang auszuführen. Ein Satz im reflexiven Passiv sagt nicht aus, dass der Vorgang tatsächlich durchgeführt wird, und er sagt auch nicht aus, das verlangt wird, dass der Vorgang durchgeführt wird. Daher ist die Aussage von *»Diese Theorie lässt sich beweisen«* tatsächlich exakt dieselbe wie von *»Diese Theorie kann bewiesen werden«.*

---

Der **Satz 2** (*»Diese Theorie ist zu beweisen«*) stellt einen anderen Subtyp eines Vorgangspassiv dar. Konstruiert wird diese Sonderform des Vorgangspassiv mit einer Form des Verbs *»sein«* (was untypisch für einen Vorgangspassiv ist), gefolgt von der Partikel *»zu«*, auf die ein Verb in der Infinitiv-Form folgt. Daher nennt man diesen Subtyp des Zustandspassiv manchmal auch *»zu+Infinitiv-Passiv«.* Hier sind drei Beispiele:

> Alle Aufgaben sind bis 14:30 Uhr zu lösen.
> Die Arbeit ist zu erledigen.
> Heute ist der Rasen zu mähen.

Allerdings transportiert der *zu+Infinitiv-Passiv* eine ganz ander Bedeutung als der zuvor behandelte reflexive Passiv. Der *zu+Infinitiv-Passiv* drückt nämlich eine notwendige Aktion aus, bzw. eine Aktion, die zwingend durchgeführt werden muss und wird daher manchmal auch als Notwendigkeits-Passiv oder Zwangs-Passiv bezeichnet.

Der Satz *»Diese Theorie ist zu beweisen«* drückt aus, dass ein Beweis geführt werden muss. Er stellt also eine Forderung bzw. einen Zwang dar. Daher ist *»Diese Theorie ist zu beweisen«* keine Umschreibung von *»Diese Theorie kann bewiesen werden«.*

---

Der **Satz 3** (*»Er lässt sich helfen«*) ist ein Beispiel für einen dritten Subtyp des Vorgangspassiv. Er wird zwar nach demselben Muster wie die zweite Form des reflexiven Passiv gebildet, drückt aber keine Möglichkeit aus, sondern eine Erlaubnis. Die Er-Person erlaubt (lässt zu), dass ihr geholfen wird. Daher wird dieser Subtyp manchmal auch *»Erlaubnis-Passiv«* genannt. Auch die Bezeichnung *»lassen-Passiv«* findet man gelegentlich. Hier sind Beispiele:

> Ich ließ mir gestern die Haare schneiden.
> Martina lässt sich einmal im Monat ihre Hände maniküren.
> Lisas Katze lässt sich jetzt gerade streicheln.

Das letzte Beispiel hätte man auch zu *»Lisas Katze lässt sich streicheln«* verkürzen können, aber dasselbe Ergebnis hätte man auch beim Verkürzen eines weiter oben stehenden Satzes (*»Lisas Katze lässt sich gerne streicheln«*) erhalten. Somit zeigt das Beispiel *»Lisas Katze lässt sich streicheln«,* dass ohne weiteren Kontext oftmals nicht ganz klar ist, ob von einer Möglichkeit oder einem Zulassen (einer Erlaubnis) die Rede ist.

Es gibt aber einen wichtigen Unterschied zum reflexiven Passiv, der sich am folgenden Beispiel zeigt:

> Ich ließ **mir** gestern die Haare schneiden.
> Ich habe eine kleine Tochter. Ich ließ **ihr** gestern die Haare schneiden.

Die fett hervorgehobenen Wörter sind keine Reflexivpronomen, sondern Personalpronomen. Es ist nämlich durchaus möglich, dass das Subjekt des Satzes zwar die Erlaubnis gibt, dass dann aber die Handlung an einer anderen Person oder Sache durchgeführt wird. Daher liegt hier keine echte Reflexivität vor, die aber das bestimmende Merkmal des reflexiven Passiv (Möglichkeitspassiv) ist.

---

Das **Satz 4** *»Ihm ist zu helfen«* ist wieder ein *zu+Infinitiv-Passiv.* (Siehe oben)

---

Der **Satz 5** *»Dagegen lässt sich argumentieren«* ist wieder ein reflexiver Passiv, wie er ganz zu Beginn beschrieben wurde. Das besondere an diesem Satz ist aber, dass er kein Subjekt enthält. Die grammatische Funktion des Subjekts ist im Satz nicht besetzt. Das schränkt jedoch die Wirkung und Funktion des reflexiven Passiv nicht ein. Der Satz rückt nach wie vor die  Möglichkeit eines Vorgangs aus.

---

Der **Satz 6** *»Dagegen ist zu argumentieren«* enthält, wie die Sätze 2 und 4, einen *zu+Infinitiv-Passiv,* über den bereits beim Satz 2 alles wichtige gesagt wurde. Aber auch dieser Satz kommt ohne Subjekt aus, und auch in diesem Fall gilt sinngemäß, was zuvor, beim Satz 5 gesagt wurde: Das Fehlen eines Subjekts schränkt die Funktion des Passiv nicht ein. In Fall des Satzes 6 heißt das, dass auch dieser Satz eine Notwendigkeit bzw. einen Zwang ausdrückt.

Answer (score 0):

Bei *sich lassen* wie in (1) und (5) ist das *sich* reflexiv. Es hat die Bedeutung *Fähigkeit/Potential haben*.

Bei (3) ist es aber nicht das reflexive *sich lassen*, das wäre dann nämlich eines von

> ihm lässt sich helfen,
>
> es lässt sich ihm helfen,

je nachdem ob man das Subjekt auslässt oder nicht.

Das *lassen* in (3) hat die Bedeutung *zulassen/erlauben*:

> (3') er erlaubt es dass ihm geholfen wird.

Vergleiche: Er lässt mich ihr helfen.

(5) ist wiederum analog zu (1). Sich ist wieder reflexiv. Das Subjekt ist ein weggelassenes *es*.

> (5') Es lässt sich dagegen argumentieren

Zu (2), (4) und (6) ist noch zu sagen dass ich diese nicht als *kann* sondern als *soll* lese.