Medialkonstruktionen (Passivsätze mit 'sich')
Ich interessiere mich dafür, ob es möglich ist, jeglichen Satz als Passiv auszudrücken, mit der Verwendung von sich.
Z.B, statt

Das wird in Betracht gezogen

folgender Satz

Das zieht sich in Betracht.

(Ich weiß nicht, ob das das beste Beispiel ist, aber es ist das, das mir eingefallen ist).
Es scheint mir, dass das korrekt ist. Duden: Sprachliche Zweifälle (2021), S. 725, sagt

Reflexive Verben mit Sachsubjekt...Das Buch liest sich leicht.  Der
Schlüssel hat sich gefunden.

und Duden: Grammatik (2002),§620 meint

Bei den sogenannten Medialkonstruktionen tritt ein (eigentlich
transitives oder intransitives) Verb mit einem Reflexivpronomen
auf... Man liest den Roman - Der Roman liest sich leicht (= Der Roman
kann leicht gelesen werden.) Man verkauft den neuen Prototyp. - Der neue Prototyp verkauft sich schlecht. (= Der neue Prototyp kann schlecht verkauft werden.) Hier lebt man gut. - Hier lebt es sich gut. (= Hier kann gut gelebt werden.)

was dem von Sprachliche Zweifälle ähnlich ist.  Aber Grammatik geht weiter

Sowohl die persönliche als auch die unpersönliche Medialkonstruktion
drückt aus, dass ein Vorgang auf eine bestimmte Art und Weise
stattfinden kann.  Es wird also eine Möglichkeit ausgedrückt.  Ein
Modaladverbial wie z.B. leicht oder gut ist hier obligatorisch.

Das scheint im Gegensatz zum zweiten Beispiel aus den Sprachlichen Zweifelfällen zu sein: Der Schlüssel hat sich gefunden, wobei es kein Modaladverbial gibt. Oder meint Grammatik hier, dass der Ausdruck dieser Möglichkeit ist nur eine Option, d.h., dass es auch das „reine Passiv" ausdrücken könnte, in welchem Fall kein Modaladverbial benötigt würde?
Meine Fragen zum Thema sind folgende:

Kann man das Passiv so normalerweise ausdrücken, d.h. mit sich?
Muss man immer ein Modaladverbial haben, d.h. kann diese Konstruktion nur die Möglichkeit eines passiven Vorgangs ausdrücken? Wenn es ein Modaladverbial geben muss, wieso dann ein Satz wie Die Schlüssel hat sich gefunden?
Wie überlappt das die „reflexiven Verben", z.B. sich bewegen?  Sich bewegen betrifft m.E. normalerweise Personen/Lebewesen (Der Mann bewegt sich).  Wäre es dann eine Medialkonstruktion mit einer Sache (Das Buch bewegt sich)?  Ich würde Nein sagen - Das Buch hat sich wegen des Erdbebens bewegt, z.B., scheint mir kein Passiv zu sein.  Wenn es ein treffendes reflexives Verb gibt (sich bewegen), muss man dann die Medialkonstruktion vermeiden?  Oder weiß man einfach Bescheid vom Kontext her? (Ich weiß nicht, ob ich das gut ausgedrückt habe).
Hat jemand eine Ahnung davon, wie diese Konstruktion mit dem spanischen pasiva refleja zu vergleichen ist, wenn es überhaupt damit zu vergleichen ist?  (Meine Deutschlehrerin, die auch Spanisch spricht, hat mir gesagt, dass es kein Äquivalent fürs pasiva refleja in Deutsch gibt).
Benutzt man diese Konstruktion oft, oder ist es besser sie zu vermeiden?


Dein erstes Beispiel versucht, einen Satz im Passiv in einen Satz im Passiv umzuwandeln. Kein Wunder, dass dabei Unsinn rauskommt.

Und von @tofro s Einwand abgesehen: "Das zieht sich ..." ist aktiv, nicht passiv! Passiv wäre "wird gezogen".

TLDR: Du wirst wahrscheinlich nicht verstanden werden, und es wird genug Muttersprachler geben, die dir geradeheraus verkaufen wollen, das sei falsch.
Ja, sich ist eine Passivumschreibung, aber keine gebräuchliche. Schließlich hat das Deutsche ja schon den Passiv mit werden, den mit sein und den mit man und einige andere. Das Hauptproblem dieser Konstruktion ist die Uneindeutigkeit: Anders als die anderen Konstruktionen ist diese nicht eindeutig Passiv.
Am häufigsten wird die Konstruktion mit einem Modaladverb ("gut", "schwer", "leicht") verwendet, wie in deinem Beispiel. Diese lassen sich aber immer mit "lassen sich" umschreiben*. Das Problem:

Medialkonstruktionen sind teilweise nicht eindeutig von Reflexivkonstruktionen abzugrenzen.
Lesartambiguitäten treten vor allem dann auf, wenn das Subjekt auch agenshafte Eigenschaften
(wie z. B. selbstinduzierte Bewegung) aufweist oder zumindest so interpretiert werden kann.[1]

Ein Beispiel aus [1]:

Der Schrank öffnet sich leicht. 
a. ‚Der Schrank öffnet sich ein bisschen.‘
b. ‚Der Schrank kann einfach geöffnet werden.‘

Was unterscheidet die "sich"-Konstruktion mit Modaladverb nun von der "man"-Konstruktion?

Als typisches Merkmal wird zudem angeführt, dass Eigenschaften des Subjektsreferenten für das dargestellte Ereignis verantwortlich sind.[1]

Ein Satz wie "Das Buch liest sich leicht" ist also eine Beschreibung des Buches.
Kann man das Modaladverb nun weglassen oder nicht? Bei Sätzen ohne Subjekt nicht, aber offensichtlich ist der Satz

Der Schlüssel hat sich gefunden

grammatikalisch, während

Das zieht sich in Betracht.

direkt mit "Unsinn" bedacht wird. (Google findet für "zieht sich nicht in Betracht" genau einen Treffer in einer Zeitung) Laut Zifonun et al. (1997,
1856) ist das Modaladverb „nahezu obligatorisch“.[1]
Für mehr kann man auch einfach direkt die Dissertation [1] lesen.
Kommen wir also zu den Fragen:

Kann man sie normalerweise / oft verwenden? Nein, besser nicht. Es geht auch nicht mit jedem Verb:


*Mit dem ICE kommt es sich leicht nach Berlin.

z.B. geht nicht.

Muss man immer ein Modaladverb haben? Nein, aber, wann man keines braucht, ist nicht ganz klar.

Wie überlappt es sich mit reflexiven Verben? Kommt auf das Verb an:



*Die Tür bewegt sich schwer.

klingt definitiv seltsam, aber

Der Wagen zieht sich schwer.

geht, auch wenn es "sich ziehen" gibt.

Wie ist es mit dem Spanischen zu vergleichen? Syntaktisch mag es ähnlich sein, das Deutsche verwendet es aber viel, viel seltener.

*: Das ist ein "lassen sich"-Satz. Alternativ: Diese umschreiben sich besser mit "lassen sich".
[1]: Dissertation Janina Behr https://doi.org/10.15488/11030

zählt auch "Es hat sich erledigt" dazu?

@rasengan__: Sicherlich. Vielleicht sollte ich erwähnen, dass bei einigen Verben diese Konstruktion "lexikalisiert" (d.h. im Sinne ins Wörterbuch aufgenommen) wird, siehe Bedeutungen 1a, 1b in https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erledigen , aber auch z.B. "sich schreiben".

Anmerken möchte ich dazu, dass Dein Beispiel mit dem ICE, auch wenn es nach offizieller Regel nicht erlaubt sein mag, umgangssprachlich sehr häufig verwendet wird und für mich daher als mindestens so natürlich klingt wie die Variante mit "man ...".

Deine Prämisse ist falsch. Im Deutschen werden diese Passiv-Ersatzformen mit dem Pronomen man/einem/einen gebildet, nicht mit dem Pronomen sich.

Das wird in Betracht gezogen.
Das zieht man in Betracht.

Dies gilt ebenso für alle Beispiele auf dieser Seite zur spanischen Grammatik:

Hier werden spanische Zeitungen verkauft.
Hier verkauft man spanische Zeitungen.

…

Hier wird nicht geraucht.
Hier raucht man nicht.


danke --  statt „Passiv" zu sagen, hätte ich womöglich „Passiv-ähnlich" sagen sollen.  Es scheint, dass es irgendeine Verbindung gibt, obwohl es etwas kompliziert ist: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73994


Der Satz »Das zieht sich in Betracht« ist kein Passivsatz.
Nein, das Pronomen sich lässt sich nicht in jeden Satz einfügen.


Der folgende Satz ist nicht korrekt:

Das zieht sich in Betracht.

Die Form »zieht« des Verbs »ziehen« ist in diesem Satz 3. Person Singular Indikativ Präsens Aktiv. Mit einem anderen Subjekt könnte »zieht« auch 2. Person Plural ein, und das sowohl Indikativ als auch Imperativ. (»Ihr zieht etwas in Betracht. Zieht das in Betracht!«) Aber in keiner grammatischen Umgebung drückt die Form »zieht« Passiv aus.
Das wären korrekte Passivsätze in derselben grammatischen Zeit (Präsens):

Vorgangspassiv

Das wird in Betracht gezogen.


Zustandspassiv

Das ist in Betracht gezogen.



Und hier mit dem Modalverb können:

Vorgangspassiv

Das kann in Betracht gezogen werden.


Zustandspassiv

Das kann in Betracht gezogen sein.




Vergleichen wir das mit Sätzen, in denen reflexive Verben korrekt mit Sachsubjekt verwendet werden:

Das Buch liest sich leicht.
Der Schlüssel hat sich gefunden.
Im neuen Büro arbeitet es sich besser.

Diese Aktivsätze enthalten alle einen gewissen Modalcharakter. Sie drücken eine Möglichkeit aus, die zum Zeitpunkt der Handlung besteht. Genau dieselbe Bedeutung kann auch in der Passivform ausgedrückt werden (als Vorgangspassiv), dazu wird aber auch noch das Modalverb können benötigt, wodurch der Charakter einer Möglichkeit explizit gekennzeichnet wird:

Das Buch kann leicht gelesen werden.
Der Schlüssel konnte gefunden werden.
Im neuen Büro kann besser gearbeitet werden.

Wenn die Möglichkeit in der Vergangenheit bereits realisiert wurde, wie beim gefundenen Schlüssel, ist auch die Form ohne Modalverb möglich (»Der Schlüssel wurde gefunden«). Im Präsens entsteht durch das Weglassen des Modalverbs aber eine andere Bedeutung. Der Satz »Das Buch wird leicht gelesen« drückt nicht genau dasselbe aus wie »Das Buch liest sich leicht.« Besser passt »Das Buch kann leicht gelesen werden.«
Wenn man diese Art der Umformung auf den zur Diskussion stehenden Satz anwendet, erhält man das:

Das kann in Betracht gezogen werden.

In dieser Passivkonstruktion tritt durch das Modalverb »kann« der Modalcharakter der Handlung klar hervor. Im Satz »Das zieht sich in Betracht« ist aber keine implizite Möglichkeit enthalten. Diese implizite Möglichkeit müsste bei einem Aktivsatz aber vorhanden sein, um das Reflexivpronomen »sich« verwenden zu können.

Mit anderer Einschätzung noch https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73994.

@DavidVogt Danke, ich werde diese gelinkte Seite anschauen.

@HubertSchölnast, danke auch - mit „Passiv" habe ich vielleicht „Passiv-ähnlich" gemeint, aber es scheint immerhin ein kompliziertes Thema zu sein.

"Das zieht sich in Betracht" bedeutet, dass eine Sache so auff"allig wird, dass sie sich (aktiv) wie ein eigenst"andiger Akteur in die Aufmerksamkeit des Betrachters einmischt. Das ist geschraubt gesprochen, aber "ahnlich einer ber"uhmten Aussage eines Fussballspielers bei einem Interview: "Das hat sich mir nicht so dargestellt."
